# Java if statement causing method to execute twice

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a quiz type game and for some reason when I add the if statement below it executes the ask method twice. You will get asked the question twice before it returns whether it is correct or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuizGame
{
private int correct;
private int wrong;
private Scanner inputScan;
private Quiz customQuiz;

public QuizGame()
{
   correct=0;
   wrong=0;
   inputScan    =   new Scanner(System.in);
}

private void startQuiz()
{
        System.out.println("Use custom upper limit? (y/n) ");
        String custom   =   inputScan.next();

        if(custom.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            System.out.println("What do you want to be your upper limit?");
            int limit   =   inputScan.nextInt();
            customQuiz  =   new Quiz(limit);
            customQuiz.ask();

            if(customQuiz.ask())
            {
                correct +=1;
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            }
            else 
            {
                wrong+=1;
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
            }
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        QuizGame quiz1  =   new QuizGame();
        quiz1.startQuiz();
    }
}
```

other class that asks the questions:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Quiz
{
    private Random rGen;
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private Scanner getInput;
    private int answer;

    public Quiz(int n1)
    {
        rGen    =   new Random();
        num1    =   rGen.nextInt(n1);
        num2    =   rGen.nextInt(n1);
        getInput   =   new Scanner(System.in);

    }

    public boolean ask()
    {
        int answer = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println("What is " + num1 + " x " + num2);
        int userAnswer  =   getInput.nextInt();

        return answer == userAnswer;   
    }
}
```

I isolated the problem and it definitely seems to be the if statement: `if(customGame.ask()) {}` in the driver class, but I don't see why. It's not like `if(customGame.ask())` calls the ask method again, it just tests if it returns true? I've also tried with just `if(customGame.ask() == true)` and still nothing.

Comment: `It's not like if(customGame.ask()) calls the ask method`, yes... Thats precisely what it does. You could remove the original call to it, or store it's value in a variable and test the variable in your if statement.

Comment: Ah sorry I guess I misunderstood the condition. I thought it just checks if it was true or false

Comment: It's calling it and checking if the result is true or false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you are calling `customQuiz.ask()` twice :

```
customQuiz.ask();

if (customQuiz.ask ())
{
    correct += 1;
    System.out.println ("Correct!");
}
```

Simply call it just once :

```
if (customQuiz.ask ())
{
    correct +=1;
    System.out.println ("Correct!");
}
```

Or (as suggested by @RobertHarvey) you can put the result of the method in a variable and use it later :

```
boolean correct = customQuiz.ask ();
if (correct)
{
    correct += 1;
    System.out.println ("Correct!");
}
```

Comment: I would have put the result of  `customQuiz.ask()`; in a variable with a meaningful name (like `answerIsCorrect`, and then checked that variable in the `if` statement, but yeah.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Initially (as I was typing the answer) I thought about putting it in a variable first (and using that variable in the condition), but since the OP doesn't use the result more than once, I decided against it.

Comment: Thanks Eran, I guess my understanding of the condtion was way off, I thought it just checked if ask() returned true/false.

Comment: @joe: it _does_ check if `ask()` returned true or false - but it checks that by _calling_ `ask()` then checking the result.